# Autofac InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope

Tags: .net, scope, autofac

I have a few dynamic modules in my application. I have settings for each of them. I want to register settings for each module before module will start. I found InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope method, but I have no I idea how it can work.

```
using System;
using Autofac;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<Settings1>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("1").As<ISettings>();
        builder.RegisterType<Settings2>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("2").As<ISettings>();

        var container = builder.Build();


        using (var lifetimeScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope("1"))
        {
            lifetimeScope.Resolve<ISettings>().Run();
        }

        using (var lifetimeScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope("2"))
        {
            container.Resolve<ISettings>().Run();
        }
    }
}


public interface ILog
{
    void Run();
}

public interface ISettings
{
    void Run();
}

public class Log : ILog
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Log");
    }
}

public class Settings1 : ISettings
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Settings1");
    }
}


public class Settings2 : ISettings
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Settings2");
    }
}
```

Example https://dotnetfiddle.net/cEw90l

Someone have an idea how it must work?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution. https://dotnetfiddle.net/fLZz4E. BeginLifetimeScope method allow to add new registrations and you can use these registrations inside your scope

```
public static void Main()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();       

    var container = builder.Build();


    using (var lifetimeScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(c => c.RegisterType<Settings1>().As<ISettings>()))
    {
        lifetimeScope.Resolve<ISettings>().Run();
    }

    using (var lifetimeScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(c => c.RegisterType<Settings2>().As<ISettings>()))
    {
        lifetimeScope.Resolve<ISettings>().Run();
    }
}
```